# Can replacing URL with pushState to a cleaner URL that redirects be bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, redirects, shopify, pushstate

We have a Shopify store. It has URL structure for blogs like `mysite.myshopify.example/blogs/blogname/article-name`

To overcome Shopify rigid URL structure and make links more human-readable and memorable we'd like to use the following technique:

1. Create redirect from non-existent (404) URL `mysite.myshopify.example/blogname/article-name` to an existing page `mysite.myshopify.example/blogs/blogname/article-name`
2. On the existing page change URL in the address bar with the following JavaScript:

```
let pretty_url_for_blog = window.location.href.replace('/blogs', '');
window.history.pushState({path:pretty_url_for_blog},'',pretty_url_for_blog);
```

– making site visitors see shorter URL `mysite.myshopify.example/blogname/article-name`

Is there any reason to think Google could penalize us for this? Which could be the arguments why it's good or bad for SEO?
Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

No penalty for this. But it is ways better to live with any rigid url structure, then to build such bypasses.

Think just about computation ressources needed for crawling of Shopware inbuild urls and for crawling of those construction. You can easy check it with monitoring the CPU utilization while rendering of pages with default urls and with such artificial urls.

Don't shoot into own knee. Googlebot can indeed crawl javascript - but nobody said, it would love this.

Answer (score 1):

The use of JavaScript to achieve this is a very bad idea. JavaScript is not always supported, sometimes it's disabled and some crawlers could not follow the link.

If something is bad for web browsers, for crawlers and for users, it's bad for SEO.

Use the file `.htaccess` to improve the permalinks, for example, to strip the `.html`. Use the `mod_rewrite`.